# How many different fractions can be made up of the numbers

Tags: fractions

How many different fractions can be made up of the numbers 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17 so that each fraction contains 2 different numbers? How many of them will be the proper fractions?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. Please provide some attempts or context to the problem, so that the community can better help you. For the second question, a hint is that the numbers are all prime.

Comment: This is not clear.  How does a fraction "contain" two different numbers?  Suppose the numbers were just $3,5$.  What would the answer be then?  What about $3,5,7$?

Comment: I guess the OP means that one number is chosen to be the numerator and one number chosen to be the denominator.

Comment: Alwats add your attempt with your question thank you.

Comment: $2{6\choose 2},\,{6\choose 2}$ @ValeriiaHordiienko .Consider the table $$\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
&3&5&7&11&13&17\\
3&\frac33&\frac53&\frac73&\frac{11}3&\frac{13}3&\frac{17}3\\
5&\frac35&\frac55&\frac75&\frac{11}5&\frac{13}5&\frac{17}5\\
7&\frac37&\frac57&\frac77&\frac{11}7&\frac{13}7&\frac{17}7\\
11&\frac3{11}&\frac5{11}&\frac7{11}&\frac{11}{11}&\frac{13}{11}&\frac{17}{11}\\
13&\frac3{13}&\frac5{13}&\frac7{13}&\frac{11}{13}&\frac{13}{13}&\frac{17}{13}\\
17&\frac3{17}&\frac5{17}&\frac7{17}&\frac{11}{17}&\frac{13}{17}&\frac{17}{17}
\end{array}$$. For 1. you take all except the diagonal,

Comment: there are $6^2-6$, for 2. all fractions below the diagonal, there are $\frac{6^2-6}{2}$ ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers of fraction which have two different numbers according to @Benjamin wang = 6C2×2!=30.  Now you can find the solution of next question. To be proper fraction I can't take the value 2!
So, the answer of next question=6C2=15

Answer (score 0):

Note that all the numbers are mutually [coprime integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) and therefore there cannot be cancellations in the fractions. Then you only need to count the number of possible pairs.